# Static lookup on Rails Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I'm trying to figure out the best way to model a simple lookup in my rails app.

I have a model, Coupon, which can be of two "types", either Percent or Fixed Amount.  I don't want to build a database table around the "type" lookup, so what I'd like to do is just have a coupon_type(integer) field on the Coupon table which can be either 1 (for Percent) or 2 (for Fixed).

What is the best way to handle this?

I found this: [Ruby on Rails Static List Options for Drop Down Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073296/ruby-on-rails-static-list-options-for-drop-down-box) but not sure how that would work when I want each value to have two fields, both ID and Description.

I'd like this to populate a select list as well.

Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: Is there any reason you have to attach a description to the integer indicating what type of coupon it is? They're both basically stating the same thing.

Comment: Should just really go with STI and use the string type column. It's slightly more data than an integer but it will just work with Rails. Can then have a parent model (`Coupon`) with two descendants (`PercentCoupon` and `FixedCoupon`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is really unlikely to change, or if it does change it will be an event significant enough to require redeployment, the easiest approach is to have a constant that defines the conditions:

```
COUPON_TYPES = {
  :percent => 1,
  :fixed => 2
}

COUPON_TYPES_FOR_SELECT = COUPON_TYPES.to_a
```

The first constant defines a forward mapping, the second in a format suitable for `options_for_select`.

It's important to note that this sort of thing would take, at most, a millisecond to read from a database. Unless you're rendering hundreds of forms per second it would hardly impact performance.

Don't worry about optimizing things that aren't perceptible problems.

Comment: Thank you.  I've decided to go the model route w/ backing DB table as you suggest - but you certainly did answer my specific question as well!